# Continued fractions and Pell's equation - numerical issues

Tags: math, precision, numeric

**Mathematical background**

[Continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) are a way to represent numbers (rational or not), with a [basic recursion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Calculating_continued_fraction_representations) to calculate it. Given a number *r*, we define `r[0]=r` and have:

```
for n in range(0..N):
    a[n] = floor(r[n])
    if r[n] == [an]: break
    r[n+1] = 1 / (r[n]-a[n])
```

where `a` is the final representation. We can also define a series of [convergents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions_and_convergents) by

```
h[-2,-1] = [0, 1]
k[-2, -1] = [1, 0]
h[n] = a[n]*h[n-1]+h[n-2]
k[n] = a[n]*k[n-1]+k[n-2]
```

where `h[n]/k[n]` converge to *r*.

[Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation) is a problem of the form `x^2-D*y^2=1` where all numbers are integers and `D` is not a perfect square in our case. A solution for a given `D` that minimizes `x` [is given by continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation#Fundamental_solution_via_continued_fractions). Basically, for the above equation, it is guaranteed that this (fundamental) solution is `x=h[n]` and `y=k[n]` for the lowest `n` found which solves the equation in the continued fraction expansion of *sqrt(`D`)*.

---

**Problem**

I am failing to get this simple algorithm work for `D=61`. I first noticed it did not solve Pell's equation for 100 coefficients, so I compared it against Wolfram Alpha's [convergents](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Convergents%5Bsqrt%5B61%5D%2C+20%5D) and [continued fraction representation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContinuedFraction%5Bsqrt%2861%29%2C+21%5D) and noticed the 20th elements fail - the representation is `3` compared to `4` that I get, yielding different convergents - `h[20]=335159612` on Wolfram compared to `425680601` for me.

I tested the code below, two languages (though to be fair, Python is C under the hood I guess), on two systems and get the same result - a diff on loop 20. I'll note that the convergents are still accurate and converge! **Why am I getting different results compared to Wolfram Alpha, and is it possible to fix it?**

---

For testing, here's a Python program to solve Pell's equation for `D=61`, printing first 20 convergents and the continued fraction representation `cf` (and some extra unneeded fluff):

```
from math import floor, sqrt  # Can use mpmath here as well.


def continued_fraction(D, count=100, thresh=1E-12, verbose=False):
    cf = []
    h = (0, 1)
    k = (1, 0)
    r = start = sqrt(D)
    initial_count = count
    x = (1+thresh+start)*start
    y = start
    while abs(x/y - start) > thresh and count:
        i = int(floor(r))
        cf.append(i)
        f = r - i
        x, y = i*h[-1] + h[-2], i*k[-1] + k[-2]
        if verbose is True or verbose == initial_count-count:
            print(f'{x}\u00B2-{D}x{y}\u00B2 = {x**2-D*y**2}')
        if x**2 - D*y**2 == 1:
            print(f'{x}\u00B2-{D}x{y}\u00B2 = {x**2-D*y**2}')
            print(cf)
            return
        count -= 1
        r = 1/f
        h = (h[1], x)
        k = (k[1], y)

    print(cf)
    raise OverflowError(f"Converged on {x} {y} with count {count} and diff {abs(start-x/y)}!")

continued_fraction(61, count=20, verbose=True, thresh=-1)  # We don't want to stop on account of thresh in this example
```

A `c` program doing the same:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    long D = 61;
    double start = sqrt(D);
    long h[] = {0, 1};
    long k[] = {1, 0};
    int count = 20;
    float thresh = 1E-12;
    double r = start;
    long x = (1+thresh+start)*start;
    long y = start;
    while(abs(x/(double)y-start) > -1 && count) {
        long i = floor(r);
        double f = r - i;
        x = i * h[1] + h[0];
        y = i * k[1] + k[0];
        printf("%ld\u00B2-%ldx%ld\u00B2 = %lf\n", x, D, y, x*x-D*y*y);
        r = 1/f;
        --count;
        h[0] = h[1];
        h[1] = x;
        k[0] = k[1];
        k[1] = y;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a wild guess, but you are using floating point numbers in your algo. And floating point numbers have limited precision. Long story short, the difference at the 20th value could be caused by the difference between the true real number sqrt(61) and its floating point approximation.  Only a comment and not an answer because I did not fully analyze your algo and hence I am not sure whether it is relevant...

Comment: @SergeBallesta That was my suspicion too, but I'm using 64 bit numbers, and fail to say a way not to use true division. If that is the answer, than a way to improve precision could be a good answer.

Comment: If you restrict yourself to integers, Python standard uses unlimited integers (getting slower and slower for huge numbers). For floats, there is the multiprecision math library, [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/) which lets you choose the precision (again, trading precision for speed). You can also use [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/), with explicit representation for fractions. Even more precision, less speed. See https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/diophantine.html#diop-dn

Comment: @JohanC Thanks, I already looked at `mpmath` and even with a precision of a 1000 get the same result. `sympy` unfortunatly is out of scope for this question as this is specifically a question on a numerical solution.

Comment: I can confirm that the problem is the floating point precision. IEE754 double have an accuracy of about 15 decimal digit. I tried to print (x/y - start), and when you diverge from Wolfram Alpha, this value is at e-15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mpmath`, python's multi-precision library can be used. Just be careful that all the important numbers are in mp format.

In the code below, `x, y and i` are standard multi-precision integers. `r` and `f` are multi-precision real numbers. Note that the initial count is set higher than 20.

```py
from mpmath import mp, mpf

mp.dps = 50  # precision in number of decimal digits

def continued_fraction(D, count=22, thresh=mpf(1E-12), verbose=False):
    cf = []
    h = (0, 1)
    k = (1, 0)
    r = start = mp.sqrt(D)
    initial_count = count
    x = 0 # some dummy starting values, they will be overwritten early in the while loop
    y = 1
    while abs(x/y - start) > thresh and count > 0:
        i = int(mp.floor(r))
        cf.append(i)
        x, y = i*h[-1] + h[-2], i*k[-1] + k[-2]
        if verbose or initial_count == count:
            print(f'{x}\u00B2-{D}x{y}\u00B2 = {x**2-D*y**2}')
        if x**2 - D*y**2 == 1:
            print(f'{x}\u00B2-{D}x{y}\u00B2 = {x**2-D*y**2}')
            print(cf)
            return
        count -= 1
        f = r - i
        r = 1/f
        h = (h[1], x)
        k = (k[1], y)

    print(cf)
    raise OverflowError(f"Converged on {x} {y} with count {count} and diff {abs(start-x/y)}!")

continued_fraction(61, count=22, verbose=True, thresh=mpf(1e-100))
```

Output is similar to wolfram's:

```
...
335159612²-61x42912791² = 3
1431159437²-61x183241189² = -12
1766319049²-61x226153980² = 1
[7, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 14, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1]
```

Comment: I was using `import mpmath as mp` and setting `mp.dps`! Thanks.